# Querying other language version of dbpedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

is there a way to query dbpedia's other language version? I would like to use data that is often non-existent in English version of dbpedia. For example, [en](http://dbpedia.org/page/Aachen_Cathedral) and [de](http://de.dbpedia.org/page/Aachener_Dom), the second one has georss property and first one does not.

My problem is, query below won't fetch Aachen's Cathedral as in English version in does not have any georss data. How can I ask de.dbpedia.org for data?

```sql
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
SELECT ?name ?abstract ?ns ?ew

WHERE{
 ?m <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract> ?abstract.
 ?m foaf:name ?name.
 ?m georss:point ?coord.

 bind( xsd:double(strbefore( ?coord, " " )) as ?ns ) 
 bind( xsd:double(strafter( ?coord, " " )) as ?ew )

 FILTER ( ?ns > 50.5 && ?ns < 50.9 && ?ew > 6.02 && ?ew < 6.14 ) 
 FILTER (LANG(?abstract) = "de")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run your query against the localized SPARQL endpoint.  In this case, try running your query against http://de.dbpedia.org/sparql.  When I do that, I get [results that include Aachen](http://de.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=PREFIX%20xsd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20%3Fname%20%3Fabstract%20%3Fns%20%3Few%0D%0A%0D%0AWHERE%7B%0D%0A%20%3Fm%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2Fabstract%3E%20%3Fabstract.%0D%0A%20%3Fm%20foaf%3Aname%20%3Fname.%0D%0A%20%3Fm%20georss%3Apoint%20%3Fcoord.%0D%0A%0D%0A%20bind%28%20xsd%3Adouble%28strbefore%28%20%3Fcoord%2C%20%22%20%22%20%29%29%20as%20%3Fns%20%29%20%0D%0A%20bind%28%20xsd%3Adouble%28strafter%28%20%3Fcoord%2C%20%22%20%22%20%29%29%20as%20%3Few%20%29%0D%0A%0D%0A%20FILTER%20%28%20%3Fns%20%3E%2050.5%20%26%26%20%3Fns%20%3C%2050.9%20%26%26%20%3Few%20%3E%206.02%20%26%26%20%3Few%20%3C%206.14%20%29%20%0D%0A%20FILTER%20%28LANG%28%3Fabstract%29%20%3D%20%22de%22%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on) (though I'm not a German speaker, so I don't know whether the description is what you're looking for).

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for. However, I now see that georss:point is not in any way consistent.